# Trying to get ForeignKey's names instead of pk in a QuerySet Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset

Im trying to make a complex queryset and I want to include my `ForeignKeys` names instead of pk. I'm using ajax to get a live feed from user inputs and print the results on a `DataTable` but I want to print the names instead of the pk. Im getting a queryset and when I `console.log` it, `sensor_name` is not in there.
My models are like this:

```
class TreeSensor(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Tree Sensors"

    field = models.ForeignKey(Field, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sensor_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, default=now)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=22, decimal_places=16, blank=True, null=True)
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=22, decimal_places=16, blank=True, null=True)

class TreeSensorMeasurement(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Tree Sensor Measurements"

    sensor = models.ForeignKey(TreeSensor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)

    soil_moisture_depth_1 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)
    soil_moisture_depth_2 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)
    soil_moisture_depth_1_filtered = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    soil_moisture_depth_2_filtered = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    soil_temperature = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)
```

And my view looks like this(I've omitted the non-essential code):

```
field_list = Field.objects.filter(user=request.user)   
tree_sensors = TreeSensor.objects.filter(field_id__in=field_list.values_list('id', flat=True))   
statSensors = (TreeSensorMeasurement.objects
              .filter(sensor_id__in=tree_sensors.values_list('id', flat=True))                                
              .filter(datetime__date__lte=To_T[0]).filter(datetime__date__gte=From_T[0])                      
              .filter(soil_moisture_depth_1__lte=To_T[1]).filter(soil_moisture_depth_1__gte=From_T[1]) 
              .filter(soil_moisture_depth_2__lte=To_T[2]).filter(soil_moisture_depth_2__gte=From_T[2])    
              .filter(soil_temperature__lte=To_T[3]).filter(soil_temperature__gte=From_T[3])                  
              .order_by('sensor', 'datetime'))
TreeData = serializers.serialize('json', statSensors)
```

The code above works correctly but I cant figure out the twist I need to do to get the `TreeSensors` name instead of pk in the frontend. An example of how I receive one instance in the frontend:

```
datetime: "2022-11-20T13:28:45.901Z"
​​​sensor: 2
​​​soil_moisture_depth_1: "166.00"
​​​soil_moisture_depth_1_filtered: "31.00"
​​​soil_moisture_depth_2: "171.00"
​​​soil_moisture_depth_2_filtered: "197.00"
soil_temperature: "11.00"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `sensor_name` is at the other end of a foreign key field in your `TreeSensorMeasurement` object, you can grab it using [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related), as in:

```
          .filter(soil_temperature__lte=To_T[3]).filter(soil_temperature__gte=From_T[3])   
          .select_related('sensor')               
          .order_by('sensor', 'datetime'))
```

In a template you could then refer to it, without further DB lookups, as:

```
{% for ss in statsensors }}
    {{ ss.sensor.sensor_name }}
{% endfor }}
```

If you're using Django Rest Framework you'll need to do a little more - this is adapted from the example at [DRF nested relationshipos](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships)

```
class TreeSensorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TreeSensor
        fields = ['sensor_name']

class TreeSensorMeasurementSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sensor = TreeSensorSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = TreeSensorMeasurement
        fields = ['sensor', 
                  'datetime', 
                  'soil_moisture_depth1',
                  'soil_moisture_depth2',
                  'soil_temoperature',
                  ]
```

Then when you call serialise it, you'll need to call your serialiser explicitly, so instead of

```
TreeData = serializers.serialize('json', statSensors)
```

use

```
TreeData = TreeSensorMeasurementSerializer(statSensors, many=True).data
```

The use of `.data` at end allows the prefetched [data relationship](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/) to be used without further lookups

Comment: This seems to work but since Im using ajax and I have to serialize my queryset to get it to frontend, It still takes pk instead of name is there a way to change that ?

Comment: Im basically storing this queryset in an array so I cant access the name like this I have to get it in another way.

Comment: Updated the answer to include DRF

Comment: Still nothing. Is it maybe because TreeSensor has more fields? sry fot not pointing that out earlier.

Comment: Shouldn't matter.  If your TreeSensor model has a string (`__str__`) function equivalent to sensor_name you can use `sensor = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)` as described in https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#inspecting-relationships

Comment: it has `sensor_name` as well as `field`. Can i somehow pick one of them?

Comment: It would just use the result of the str function which you might be able to split.  I'm surprised the nested approach doesn't work though.  Is there anything in the sensor section of the JSON?

Comment: Its the same as the one pointed out in the answer. I tried removing ` .filter(sensor_id__in=tree_sensors.values_list('id', flat=True))` but it seems that was not the problem either

Comment: The thing is it works by the default template approach you pointed out. It doesnt show anything in serializer though.

Comment: You may need to call TreeSensorMeasurementSerializer explicitly,  as in https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a read-only serializer field in `TreeSensorMeasurementSerializer`

```
sensor_name = serializer.ReadOnlyField(source='sensor.sensor_name')
```

Comment: Its not working. Is it maybe because TreeSensor has more fields? Is there another import needed other than `serializers` from `rest framework`